# Severalnines Clustercontrol Alternative software?

Tags: automation, mysql, postgresql, mongodb, clustering

I have been dealing with ClusterControl software to provision MySQL cluster and monitor and scale from last few weeks. But they are not really responsive I tried to reach them to get a quote but they just simply don't respond you, and I am looking for similar solution. It can be paid or open source

> [ClusterControl](https://hub.docker.com/r/severalnines/clustercontrol/) is a management and automation software for database
>   clusters. It helps deploy, monitor, manage and scale your database
>   cluster. This Docker image comes with ClusterControl installed and
>   configured with all of its components so you can immediately use it to
>   deploy new set of database servers/clusters or manage existing
>   database servers/clusters.
>
> Supported database servers/clusters:
>
> - Galera Cluster for MySQL Percona
> - XtraDB Cluster
> - MariaDB Galera Cluster
> - MySQL Replication
> - MySQL single instance
> - MySQL Cluster (NDB)
> - MongoDB sharded cluster
> - MongoDB replica set
> - PostgreSQL (single instance/streaming replication)

Comment: I'm looking for an alternative too - i found this https://www.percona.com/software/database-tools/percona-monitoring-and-management and am evaluating now - i just need monitoring and analysis -the install is done and adding a new node to a cluster is fairly simple

Comment: Let me check that too.

Comment: @ManseUK PERCONA MONITORING AND MANAGEMENT is not able to provision DB clusters. Only monitoring.